# Do I need a "wired sensor bar" to play Skyward Sword on Wii U?

Tags: wii-u, zelda-skyward-sword

To play Wii's Skyward Sword on Wii U, is a Wii Motion Plus and Nunchuk *all* what I need?

In particular, do I also need to buy a Wired Sensor Bar?

Comment: You are supposed to already have a sensor bar from your purchase of a WiiU.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will also need the Wired Sensor Bar. When you are launching the game, there is a step where you have to calibrate the Wiimote with the Sensor Bar. After that calibration you don't need it anymore (except if you want to calibrate your Wiimote another time during the game phase), but it will be needed each time you launch the game again.

Comment: Surely you need it for certain game functions (like bow and arrow), right? Why would they add the aim calibration if it's not used in game anywhere?

Comment: @MageXy. This answer is correct, the sensor bar is only used for calibration. Sadly, aiming doesn't use the sensor bar at all; it therefore has a relatively long reaction time, and you'll often need to re-center. The reason the sensor bar is needed during calibration, is so the Wiimote knows how it is oriented; "forward" is where the sensor bar is, after all.

Comment: @Nolonar Huh. That's weird. That seems counterintuitive to me, but then again I'm just a layman.

Comment: @MageXy. I think they wanted to provide a similar experience to *Wii Sports Resorts*, where you'd hold the Wiimote as if it were a real bow. Instead of pointing it towards the screen, you'd point it upwards. That's probably the reason it couldn't use the sensor bar.

Comment: @Nolonar you still point at the screen though. But you're probably right because I had to recalibrate a few times when playing.

Comment: Technically, you do not need an actual sensor bar. While the remote needs to be calibrated, the calibration is done by the remote itself picking up the two points of infrared light that the bar gives off. The bar does not communicate with anything. You can therefore replace it with two other sources of infrared light - such as candles. EDIT: Just to show that I am not making it up - one of several videos proving that it works: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DYzN34p3CqU